# How to apply column alignment to datagrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, datagrid, alignment

I have an VB.Net ASP page that I have a datagrid on it with 5 columns and a few rows of data. The page will show the data and grid just fine.  I need to now apply alignment to the datagrid columns.

```
dgLast5Bills.DataSource = dtBill
dgLast5Bills.DataBind()
dgLast5Bills.Columns(0).ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
```

The code above will error out when it hits the line for the alignment.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: at which event you are using this code?

Comment: Page Load event for the page.

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: Are you sure `dtBill` has column? Have you try breakpoint?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't align the columns in the designer code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dgLast5Bills.Columns(0).ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center` code give you `Index was out of range` error because in your `aspx` page you have not define any column, so at compile time there is no `0` index.

You should try this.

```
  Sub Item_Bound(sender As Object, e As DataGridItemEventArgs) 
     If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
         e.Item.Cells(0).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
     End If         
  End Sub
```

[For more reading look at it. DataGrid.ItemDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx#Y2071)

Comment: @JPJedi: Please delete `dgLast5Bills.Columns(0).ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center ` from page load first.

Comment: I got it.  I had to fix the databinding some.  Thanks @jams